# getting lsmod output from android device to PC

Tags: android

I am fairly new to android and I was wondering if there is a way of running lsmod on a PC and saving the resulting output there as a text file. Apologies if this is a simple question but, as I said I am a newbie to android.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the SDK on your PC, so you have adb, with the right drivers for your device.
2. Ensure that adb is in your path on your PC, and start a shell on your PC.
3. Then

   ```
   adb shell lsmod > lsmod.txt
   ```

   on the PC will do what you need.

It doesn't need root.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I appreciate the help.